# Can Earl Grey be used with XCUITest

Tags: earlgrey

I started using XCUITest in Xcode 7 to add UI tests for the app I was testing . 
As I had issues with XCUITest while entering text fields, I wanted to try EarlGrey framework for adding UITests and not unit Tests.

I completed all the set up mentioned in https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/install-and-run.md 
only to read this at the end

" Because EarlGrey is based on XCTest, creating your first test in Xcode is as easy as creating a new Unit Test Case Class. Be careful not to confuse Unit Test Case Class with UI Test Case Class. UI Test Case Class uses the new UI Testing feature added to XCTest and isn’t yet compatible with EarlGrey"

Does this mean the Early grey framework can be used only for Unit tests and not for  XCUITests on Xcode 7 ? 
Has anyone tried writing XCUITests with EarlGrey framework ?

Answer (score 1):

It won't work today. They're working on it and you can follow their progress here:
https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/issues/63